# ASCII error with my Django API

Tags: python, django

I'm learning a tutorial in order to study Django so I'm really new with that.
I started a project which is named `etat_civil` and I created an application which is named `blog`.

I get this kind of things :

[image]

My `blog views.py` file looks like :

```
#-*- coding : utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def home (request) :
    text = u"""<h1>Bienvenue sur mon blog ! </h1>
           <p>Les crêpes bretonnes ça tue des mouettes en plein vol ! </p>"""
    return HttpResponse(text)
```

and my `etat_civil urls.py` file looks like :

```
#-*- coding : utf-8 -*-

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accueil$', views.home),
]
```

Then, in the terminal I executed the command line : `python manage.py run server`

But I get this error and I don't know from where is this error :

```
macbook-pro-de-valentin:etat_civil valentinjungbluth$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x1109e1050>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/valentinjungbluth/etat_civil/etat_civil/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    from blog import views
  File "/Users/valentinjungbluth/etat_civil/blog/views.py", line 9
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file /Users/valentinjungbluth/etat_civil/blog/views.py on line 10, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Thank you so much if you could help me ;)

Comment: If you wanted to show your directory structure by attaching such a large image, well, it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra space in your source code encoding definition

Change this:

```
#-*- coding : utf-8 -*-
```

To this:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```